# how to fix “No appropriate likelihood could be inferred” for network meta-analysis in R?

Tags: r

I am currently learning Network meta-analysis in R with "gemtc",and "netmeta". 
As I try to fit the GLM model for analysis, I encountered this error message " No appropriate likelihood could be inferred" .

My code are:

```
gemtc_network_numbers <-mtc.network(data.ab=diabetes_data,treatments=treatments)

mtcmodel<-mtc.model(network=gemtc_network_numbers,type="consistency",factor=2.5, n.chain=4, linearModel="random")

mtcresults <- mtc.run(mtcmodel, n.adapt = 20000, n.iter=100000, thin=10,   sampler="rjags")

# View results summary 
print(summary(mtcresults))
```

My data are:

```
> diabetes_data
   study treatment responder samplesize
1      1         1        45        410
2      1         3        70        405
3      1         4        32        202
4      2         1       119       4096
5      2         4       154       3954
6      2         5       302       6766
7      3         2         1        196
8      3         5         8        196
9      4         1       138       2800
10     4         5       200       2826
11     5         3       799       7040
12     5         4       567       7072
13     6         1       337       5183
14     6         3       380       5230
15     7         2       163       2715
16     7         6       202       2721
17     8         1       449       2623
18     8         6       489       2646
19     9         5        29        416
20     9         6        20        424
21    10         4       177       4841
22    10         6       154       4870
23    11         3        86       3297
24    11         5        75       3272
25    12         1       102       2837
26    12         6       155       2883
27    13         4       136       2508
28    13         5       176       2511
29    14         3       665       8078
30    14         4       569       8098
31    15         2       242       4020
32    15         3       320       3979
33    16         3        37       1102
34    16         5        43       1081
35    16         6        34       2213
36    17         3       251       5059
37    17         4       216       5095
38    18         1       335       3432
39    18         6       399       3472
40    19         2        93       2167
41    19         6       115       2175
42    20         5       140       1631
43    20         6       118       1578
44    21         1        93       1970
45    21         3        97       1960
46    21         4        95       1965
47    22         2       690       5087
48    22         4       845       5074
```

Thanks for your help.

Angel

Comment: The problem is when I run:                                                                    'mtcmodel <- mtc.model(network=gemtc_network_numbers, type="consistency", factor = 2.5, n.chain = 4, linearModel="fixed")'
                                                                                                                                    Error in mtc.model(network = gemtc_network_numbers, type = "consistency",  :
 No appropriate likelihood could be inferred. Please specify one.

Answer (score -1):

You have to solution :
1- Replace your responder variable by "responders" and your samplesize variable by "sampleSize".

or 
2- Use for example : mtc.model(...,likelihood="poisson",link="log")).

Comment: This is very helpful. Thanks. Bibi. The first option did not work. But my problem solved by renaming variables to "responders" and "sampleSize". As a beginner to Network Meta analysis,  could you let me know how to make the option 2 work?  Thanks again.